# Change of variables chain rule

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

In wikipedia's article regarding the "change of variables" method of solving PDEs, the following example is used:

> $ \dfrac{\partial V}{\partial t} + \dfrac{1}{2} S^2\dfrac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2} + S\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial S} - V = 0.$
>
> is reducible to the heat equation
>
> $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial \tau} = \dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$
>
> by the change of variables
>
> - $V(S,t) = v(x(S),\tau(t))$
> - $x(S) = \ln(S)$
> - $\tau(t) = \dfrac{1}{2} (T - t)$
> - $v(x,\tau)=\exp(-(1/2)x-(9/4)\tau) u(x,\tau)$
>
> in these steps:
>
> - Replace $V(S,t)$ by $v(x(S),\tau(t))$ and apply the chain rule to get
>
> $$\dfrac{1}{2}\left(-2v(x(S),\tau)+2 \dfrac{\partial\tau}{\partial t} \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial \tau} +S\left(\left(2 \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial S} + S\dfrac{\partial^2 x}{\partial S^2}\right) 
> \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x} + 
> S \left(\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial S}\right)^2 \dfrac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x^2}\right)\right)=0.$$
>
> - Replace $x(S)$ and $\tau(t)$ by $\ln(S)$ and $\dfrac{1}{2}(T-t)$ to get
>
> $$\dfrac{1}{2}\left(-2v(\ln(S),\dfrac{1}{2}(T-t))-\dfrac{\partial v(\ln(S),\dfrac{1}{2}(T-t))}{\partial\tau}+\dfrac{\partial v(\ln(S),\dfrac{1}{2}(T-t))}{\partial x} +\dfrac{\partial^2 v(\ln(S),\dfrac{1}{2}(T-t))}{\partial x^2}\right)=0.$$
>
> - Replace $\ln(S)$ and $\dfrac{1}{2}(T-t)$ by $x(S)$ and $\tau(t)$ and divide both sides by $\dfrac{1}{2}$ to get
>
> $$-2 v-\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial\tau}+\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}+ \dfrac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x^2}=0.$$
>
> - Replace $v(x,\tau)$ by $\exp(-(1/2)x-(9/4)\tau) u(x,\tau)$ and divide through by $-\exp(-(1/2)x-(9/4)\tau)  u(x,\tau)$ to yield the heat equation.

Now my question lies in the first step. I don't get how the $\dfrac{1}{2}S^2\dfrac{\partial ^2 V}{\partial S^2}$ and $S\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial S}$ terms are transformed in that first part. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 1):

First, multiply the Black-Scholes equation by $2$ to get

$$ 2\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial t} + S^2\dfrac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2} + 2S\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial S} - 2V = 0. $$

Using $V = \nu(x(S),\tau(t))$, write

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}  &= \frac{\partial \nu}{\partial S} = \frac{\partial \nu}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial S};\\
\frac{\partial^{2}V}{\partial S^{2}} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial S}\frac{\partial \nu}{\partial S} = \frac{\partial}{\partial S}\left( \frac{\partial \nu}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial S}\right) = \frac{\partial}{\partial S}\frac{\partial \nu}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial S} \right) + \frac{\partial \nu}{\partial x}\frac{\partial^{2}x}{\partial S^{2}} = \frac{\partial^{2}\nu}{\partial x^{2}}\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial S}\right)^{2} + \frac{\partial^{2}x}{\partial S^{2}}\frac{\partial \nu}{\partial x};\\
\frac{\partial V}{\partial t} &= \frac{\partial \nu}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial \nu}{\partial \tau}\frac{\partial \tau}{\partial t}.
\end{align*}

Sub this all in to get

$$2\frac{\partial \nu}{\partial \tau}\frac{\partial \tau}{\partial t} + S^{2}\left(\frac{\partial^{2}\nu}{\partial x^{2}}\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial S}\right)^{2} + \frac{\partial^{2}x}{\partial S^{2}}\frac{\partial \nu}{\partial x} \right) +2S\frac{\partial \nu}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial S} - 2\nu(x(S),\tau(t)) = 0.$$

Group in terms of $\frac{\partial \nu}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial^{2} \nu}{\partial x^{2}}$ and divide by 2.